# How do I insert multiple figures into multiple tables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, ms-word, report

Here's what I'm trying to achieve in MATLAB:

Page 1

```
______________
|      |     |
| Fig1 | Fig2|
|      |     |
|______|_____|
|      |     |
| Fig3 | Fig4|
|      |     |
|______|_____|
```

Page 2

```
______________
|      |     |
| Fig5 | Fig6|
|      |     |
|______|_____|
|      |     |
| Fig7 | Fig8|
|      |     |
|______|_____|
```

I can't figure out the parameter to pass InsertBreak to get a new page:

```
word = actxserver('Word.Application');

word.Visible = 1;

op = invoke(word.Documents,'Add');

active=word.ActiveDocument;

%% Table 1
% Create 4x4 table
range=word.Selection.Range;
shapes=word.Selection.InlineShapes;
t=invoke(word.ActiveDocument.Tables,'add',range,2,2);

% fill each cell with an image, image will fit to table
invoke(shapes,'addpicture',fullfile(pwd, 'fig1.wmf'));

invoke(word.Selection,'moveright',1,1);
invoke(shapes,'addpicture',fullfile(pwd, 'fig2.wmf'));

invoke(word.Selection,'moveright',1,2);
invoke(shapes,'addpicture',fullfile(pwd, 'fig3.wmf'));

invoke(word.Selection,'moveright',1,1);
invoke(shapes,'addpicture',fullfile(pwd, 'fig4.wmf'));

%% Table 2, I want this on a new page
invoke(word.Selection,'InsertBreak',2); % how do I get the next stuff on a new page?
range=word.Selection.Range;
shapes=word.Selection.InlineShapes;
t=invoke(word.ActiveDocument.Tables,'add',range,1,2);

invoke(shapes,'addpicture',fullfile(pwd, 'fig1.wmf'));
invoke(word.Selection,'moveright',1,1);
invoke(shapes,'addpicture',fullfile(pwd, 'fig2.wmf'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in place of your `InsertBreak` line. It moves the start of the selection to the end of the document. Without the move your code is inserting a page break inside a table cell.

```
invoke(word.Selection, 'MoveStart', 6);
invoke(word.Selection, 'InsertBreak');
```